# Notification not being shown on device with api 24 but is shown on device with api 26

Tags: android, android-notifications

The code below shows a notification in the tray. Notifications are displayed on my device running api 26, but not on my device running api 24. There obviously something wrong with my code, but I'm not sure what it is.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, TranscriptActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("path", path);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    String channelId = "new_message_channel";
    Uri defaultSoundUri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelId)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_person_black_24dp)
                    .setContentTitle(title)
                    .setContentText(messageBody)
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                    .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(0 , notificationBuilder.build());
```

the channel was created in the 1st activity:

```
private void createNotificationChannel() {
    // Create the NotificationChannel, but only on API 26+ because
    // the NotificationChannel class is new and not in the support library
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        CharSequence name = "Messages channel";
        String description = "Channel for incoming direct messages";
        int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT;
        NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel("new_message_channel", name, importance);
        channel.setDescription(description);
        // Register the channel with the system; you can't change the importance
        // or other notification behaviors after this
        NotificationManager notificationManager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
    }
}
```

Comment: can you try to use non-zero value as notification Id: `notificationManager.notify(1 , notificationBuilder.build());`

Comment: @Sagar sadly, that didnt work

Comment: I created the notification channel, it works on api 26

Answer (score 0, accepted):

turns out the device running api 24 didn't have a valid messaging token

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingServices extends FirebaseMessagingService {
    private NotificationChannel mChannel;
    private NotificationManager notifManager;
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(remoteMessage.getData());
                displayCustomNotificationForOrders(jsonObject.getString("title"), jsonObject.getString("description"));
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    private void displayCustomNotificationForOrders(String title, String description) {
        if (notifManager == null) {
            notifManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService
                    (Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        }
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            NotificationCompat.Builder builder;
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, Dashboard.class);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent;
            int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH;
            if (mChannel == null) {
                mChannel = new NotificationChannel
                        ("0", title, importance);
                mChannel.setDescription(description);
                mChannel.enableVibration(true);
                notifManager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel);
            }
            builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "0");

            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP |
                    Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
            pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 1251, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
            builder.setContentTitle(title)  
                    .setSmallIcon(getNotificationIcon()) // required
                    .setContentText(description)  // required
                    .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource
                            (getResources(), R.mipmap.logo))
                    .setBadgeIconType(R.mipmap.logo)
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                    .setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri
                            (RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION));
            Notification notification = builder.build();
            notifManager.notify(0, notification);
        } else {

            Intent intent = new Intent(this, Dashboard.class);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = null;

            pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 1251, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

            Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
            NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                    .setContentTitle(title)
                    .setContentText(description)
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getBaseContext(), R.color.colorPrimary))
                    .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                    .setSmallIcon(getNotificationIcon())
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                    .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().setBigContentTitle(title).bigText(description));

            NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            notificationManager.notify(1251, notificationBuilder.build());
        }
    }

    private int getNotificationIcon() {
        boolean useWhiteIcon = (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP);
        return useWhiteIcon ? R.mipmap.logo : R.mipmap.logo;
    }
}
```